# Convex open subset as the domain required for convex optimisation

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Can we help unpack this statement from my Mathematical Economics course pack:

> Let $f$ be a continuous twice differentiable function whose domain is a convex open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is a concave function on U and $Df(x_0) = 0$ then $x_0$ is a global maximum of $f$ on $U$

The first sentence is the part I'm struggling with, primarily the **"Convex open subset"** and I want to understand both the intuition and the technical mechanics behind the intuition. My understanding so far:

1. **Continuous:** This is necessary for our function to be differentiable across the entire domain so that we can find our stationary point.
2. **Twice Differentiable:** I'm assuming this is so we can access the second derivative for a hessian test to check if the function is indeed concave or not.
3. **Domain is Convex:** I understand this is a condition for convex optimisation, and I can kind of appreciate intuitively that if the domain wasn't a convex set. e.g. it was a donut. Then the function could potentially be discontinuous. But I feel like there is more to it, and maybe my explanation is wrong/not even close.
4. **Domain is an Open Subset**: This I really don't understand. How is an open subset going to help us vs a closed subset? All I can think of is something to do with maximum values at the edge of the domain, but I would have thought a closed subset would make more sense for this. (In the same way that the set of feasible vectors for our Lagrangian needs to be compact i.e. closed).

- Also given that the feasible set for a constrained optimisation problem is within or on the boundary of the constraint, and the constraint is presumably a subset of the domain, I'm even less clear about this condition on the domain of $f$.

I have searched Quora, Stack, YouTube and my Textbooks...And am struggling to come up with satisfactory answers. Apologies if this is basic or I have missed a post, but I will be immensely grateful for some thoughts!

Thanks!

Comment: Your text is wrong as written. It should read let $f\in C^2$. Then it will be correct.

Comment: Regarding 3) If I recall correctly, strictly speaking, you don't need convex domain, a weaker form will suffice. This comes from the proof of Taylor's theorem, the estimate on the remainder is achieved by application of the mean value theorem (the exact form, I do not remember, but to apply it, you need some sort of "closure under line segment property" on your domain, convexity is certainly sufficient, though may or may not be necessary).

Comment: Regarding 4) It's awkward to talk about closed sets because of what happens on boundary points. Going back to my first comment, one needs $f\in C^2$ to apply Taylor's Theorem, namely $f(x+h) = f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T h+\frac{1}{2}h^T \nabla^2 f(z)h$ for some $z \in (x-h,x+h)$. Applying that $0\succsim\nabla^2 f(x)  $, one gets by a density and continuity argument that provided $h$ is sufficiently small, $0\succsim\nabla^2 f(c)$, which is enough to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open part should be fairly intuitive if you unpack the definition of the $Df$ map; you need to have a 'neighbourhood' around a point if you want to know how the function changes in all directions near that. Convexity is there most likely to ensure that to find how it changes near a given point, you can study it restricted on lines joining that point and any other point in the set. Note that convexity is a nice sufficient condition that ensure that your manipulations are meaningful but most likely they are not necessary/ the most general conditions

Comment: HI @RohanDimishe thank you for that!

1) The open set point makes sense. I.e. if our maximum was on the edge of the domain, we'd need to see how the unction behaves in all directions on this edge, we can't do that if the edge has a hard limit? Does that mean the derivative wouldn't be defined on the edge?

2) Is there anywhere I can read to unpack your convexity point more?

Comment: I guess technically there is nothing stopping you from defining derivatives on non open sets, but note that many of the crucial theorems like derivative being $0$ on local extrema rely on the open set structure anyway; I think convexity is a particularly popular thing, there are various books on Convex Analysis you could search; I only think of it as  sets with the nice property that the usual lines between two points are inside it; and lines are always nice things to work with right...

Comment: Hi @RohanDimishe, I was just reading your answer again. And I'm slightly confused by your use of necessary and sufficient, shouldn't it be the other way round? My understanding is that sufficient conditions are those s.t. if A is sufficient for B, then the presence of A means that B must happen. Where as if A is necessary for B, then B cannot happen without A, but may not actually happen even if A happens. So in our case, the conditions mentioned are surely necessary for a meaningful manipulation, but do not guarantee it actually is (i.e. they are not  sufficient?)

Comment: @CormJack sorry for replying so late, but what I meant is existence of derivative/convex open sets etc, is sufficient to conclude say $x_0$ is an extremum, but is not necessary, for you can have extrema for non differentiable functions on bad sets